# maven do not repack dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I use maven assembly plugin to collect all dependencies into one jar file. How can I tell maven not to repack dependencies and include them as jar files into resulting jar?

Currently I use following plugin configuration.

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>package.Program</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

wanted structure of jar file:

```
my-jar-with-dependencies.jar
|-dependency1.jar
|-|-class1.class
|-dependency2.jar
|-|-class2.class
|-...........
```

and not

```
my-jar-with-dependencies.jar
|-class1.class
|-class2.class
|-.............
```

Comment: Jar can't contain other jars. `maven-assembly-plugin` can create zip files (`<format>zip</format>` in your assembly descriptor file), but one need to unpack it to actually run the application.

Comment: @dma_k, but eclipse is able to export jar with embedded jars

Comment: So what do you do next with this jar? Can you execute it from command line?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to specify when the assembly plugn should be run or not. I this is the case you should consider creating a [build profile](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles.html) and add the assembly plugin configuration to the new profile.

In pom.xml add:

```
<project>
...
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myprofile</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>package.Program</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
...
</project>
```

When you want maven to run the assembly plugin you can then use the -P switch to the 'mvn' script like this:

```
mvn -Pmyprofile clean package
```

Comment: No, I wish to set assembly plugin not to unpack dependencies into resulting jar file. It has to include them as jar files.

Comment: you should use the zip-with-dependencies descriptor ref then